# What is the best method to apply priority on database records to show in user interface?

Tags: database, record

I would like to know what is the best way to apply priority for database records to showin user interface?
I tried 2 methods, but I have problem with both of them in different applications and situations.

> I have id and priority fields in each table inside database.

**Method1:** I fill priority as `0` by default.
**Method2:** I fill priority as same as `id` value.

After that, I put 2 arrows that indicate user want to downgrade or upgrade the priority. User can click on them to apply new priority for that row.

[image]

Which of two methods above is better ?

Comment: Both do not work because they can result in duplicated priority values. Just an idea: use hierarchyid. https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql+server+reorder+rows seems to turn up a few ideas as well.

Comment: @usr can you tell me what is the best value to insert in priority field at first ?

Comment: If I knew I would have told you. You can solve this problem yourself by doing some research. What did your research turn out?

Comment: Maybe something like this I have to use ... http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

Comment: Can you describe what problems you have with the first method?